# How to click on image using selenium

Tags: python, image, selenium, selenium-webdriver, onclick

I'm trying to click on button that contains this code :

```
<div style="text-align:center" id="plus_res">
<img src="https://www.tunlancer.com/theme/images/plus_resv2.png" align="plus d'elements" title="plus d'elements" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="plus_resultat()">
</div>
```

i've tried :

```
image = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[contains(@src,'https://www.tunlancer.com/theme/images/plus_resv2.png')]")

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", image)
```

```
driver.find_element_by_id('plus_res').click()
```

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="plus_res"]/img').click()
```

But it's showing the NoSuchElementException .
How can i fix it please?

Comment: Could you share what is your failing solution ?
btw. Is this image (https://www.tunlancer.com/theme/images/plus_resv2.png) is in your private network ? It's not available.

Comment: check the code i've added my solutions, yes it's private

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly you have to add delay.
Something like this should work :

```
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('img[src="https://www.tunlancer.com/theme/images/plus_resv2.png"]').click()
```

Comment: Just please keep in mind that hardcoded wait intervals are not perfect solution. It might happen that page will load longer (of course 5 sec seems to be secure) ... or that sum of all sleeps in test suite makes testing too long.

So the solution proposed by @Prophet could be better in long term - if of course you will manage it to work. Test would wait for the image to click - up to 20 seconds of timeut.

Comment: @poleszcz thank you for the information !! i'll keep that on mind and work on it

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are missing a delay / wait before accessing that element.
Please try this:

```py
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//img[@onclick="plus_resultat()"]'))).click()
```

You will need the following imports:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Also possibly the element is inside an iframe.

Comment: Maybe it is inside an iframe?